# Angular material select, how to make input to turn native in mobile phones?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have select in my component :

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="food">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{food.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

The problem is that I need that this select would work on mobile like native does. (Ios and Android specific). How to make that ?